# Plot only Trading View historical data

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

My biggest problem is that I ONLY want the historical data on my indicator because the real-time is too variable and prints a bunch of buy/sell signals that I do not want. Below is the code I have so far.

Essentially, I want the historical alerts and I want only the historical data to show when I have TV loaded.

Disclaimer: I used this open-source code from Mehdi and have been editing it to fix it/get what I need from it.

Thank you for anyone's time that helps here.

```
// © SRJRainey
//@version=2
strategy("TDI - Traders Dynamic Index ", shorttitle="TDIMH")

rsiPeriod = input(13, minval = 1, title = "RSI Period")
bandLength = input(34, minval = 1, title = "Band Length")
lengthrsipl = input(1, minval = 0, title = "Fast MA on RSI")
lengthtradesl = input(9, minval = 1, title = "Slow MA on RSI")
p1 = input("15", title = "Signal Timeframe", type = string)

src = close // Source of Calculations (Close of Bar)

r = rsi(src, rsiPeriod) // RSI of Close
ma = sma(r, bandLength) // Moving Average of RSI
offs = (1.6185 * stdev(r, bandLength)) // Offset
up = ma + offs // Upper Bands
dn = ma - offs // Lower Bands
mid = (up + dn) / 2 // Average of Upper and Lower Bands
fastMA = sma(r, lengthrsipl) // Moving Average of RSI 2 bars back
slowMA = sma(r, lengthtradesl) // Moving Average of RSI 7 bars back

hline(50)
indexHighTf = barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0
indexCurrTf = barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1
slowMA1 = security(tickerid, p1, slowMA)
fastMA1 = security(tickerid, p1, fastMA)
up1 = security(tickerid, p1, up)
dn1 = security(tickerid, p1, dn)
mid1 = security(tickerid, p1, mid)

plot(up1, "Upper Band", color = #3286c3, linewidth = 2) // Upper Band
plot(dn1, "Lower Band", color = #3286c3, linewidth = 2) // Lower Band
plot(mid1, "Middle of Bands", color = yellow, linewidth = 2) // Middle of Bands
plot(slowMA1, "Slow MA", color=green, linewidth=2) // Plot Slow MA
plot(fastMA1, "Fast MA", color=red, linewidth=1) // Plot Fast MA

if (crossover(fastMA1, slowMA1)) strategy.entry("sell", strategy.long, comment="Buy")

if (crossunder(fastMA1, slowMA1)) strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, comment="Sell")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [History reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) to access historical data.

So, for example, you can do

`crossover(fastMA1[1], slowMA1[1])` to see if the crossover took place one bar ago.